# Daily quota limit for Maps Service exceeded, but no quota is shown as used

Tags: google-maps, google-apps-script, google-directions-api

I have a Google Sheet with a list of places. For each place, I aim to calculate its distance from all the other places one at a time, with the aim to find the ones that are nearby to each other.

My `getDistance()` function below returns a float corresponding to the distance in miles between two addresses:

*(I've redacted my API key and Client ID)*

```
function getDistance(from, to) {
  var key = '{my-API-key}';
  var clientID = '{my-client-id}';
  Maps.setAuthentication(clientID, key);
  var directions = Maps.newDirectionFinder()
                       .setOrigin(from)
                       .setDestination(to)
                       .setMode(Maps.DirectionFinder.Mode.DRIVING)
                       .getDirections();
  return parseFloat(directions.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text);
};
```

**things I've tried:**

- enabled the Distance Matrix API, and the Directions API.
- signed up for and enabled billing in the Google Cloud Console (as directed by a Google Support rep to no avail)

Neither of these enabled APIs show any usage in the API console, but my script stills errors with:

> Service invoked too many times for one day: route

I do not see any relevant quota set for this, so what am I not understanding?

Comment: To be clear: you have a Maps API for Business account, and you supply your client ID and signing key from the Google Enterprise Support Portal? Or are you using some client ID and client secret from somewhere else? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/maps/maps#setauthenticationclientid-signingkey  https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#keysystem Note the requirements in the table regarding key restrictions.

Comment: Also, in this question (and in the one you asked previously but deleted so you could re-ask it, *tsk tsk*), you don't mention how many of these requests are being performed.

Comment: In addition to the above, Do you have any "key restrictions" [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/apiui/credential)